# Need some suggestions on how to decode a protobuf file which is downloaded from HERE-OLP in binary format

Tags: java, here-olp, protobuf-3

We have a use case where the maps are downloaded from HERE-OLP. The files are in Protobuf3 (encoded as binary) format. How do we decode the file and read the content in it? Appreciate any recommendations or Java source code who have done this before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm understanding your question properly but if you go to the catalog layer you downloaded the data from, look for the Schema tab. If your user has access to it (all the HERE Map Content layer schemas are public), it provides the schemas as Maven dependency elements that you can copy into a pom.xml file or you can click the "Download schema" button to download the schema jars as a zip file.

For actual code, go to the Code examples in the documentation, many of the examples read and parse protobuf data. A good starting point is the OLP Developer Tutorials one under the "Get Started" category.